# I am using processing.js in a web page with script tag. How can I change the height of the script tag?

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I have created a script tag to put in processing code. When I put it on a website it only takes up a small fraction of the web page despite it having 1142 as a height.

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="processingJS/processing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="processingJS/init.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script type="application/processing" height="1142" width="1142">
        noStroke();


    draw = function() {
        fill(mouseX, mouseY, 0);
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 100, 100);
    };

        </script><canvas></canvas>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you read/looked at any of the demo/examples for this `processingJS` plugin? I'm sure it will have something to explain how to adjust things to fit your needs.... Maybe try adding `size(300,200);` This is `Javascript` driven and uses a `canvas` to display the output so trying to add a size to a script tag isn't going to do anything. I suggest you read the documentation http://processingjs.org/learning/

Answer (score 0):

Like NewToJS said in their comment, you need to use the `setup()` and `size()` functions.

More info is available in [the reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/size_/):

> Defines the dimension of the display window in units of pixels. The
>   `size()` function must be the first line in `setup()`. If `size()` is not
>   called, the default size of the window is 100x100 pixels. The system
>   variables `width` and `height` are set by the parameters passed to the
>   size() function.

You should also really get into the habit of doing some research before you post a question. This is covered in pretty much every Processing and Processing.js tutorial, so a little reading would have gone a long way for you here.